# What are the common Solidty smart contract libraries like openzeppelin?

Tags: solidity

I am new in smart contract, can anyone recommend some Solidity library that experienced developers often use.
And is there a list of widely-used libraries? or where can i find some widely used libraries?

Comment: Take a look at my [prb-contracts](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-contracts) library, which offers various ERC20 extensions that you might find useful. I'm also using only custom errors, no revert reason strings.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it's a greate job for new.